# is there any relationship between zoom level and latitude longitude in OVERPASS API?

Tags: java, javafx, zooming, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am working on project : 
I need to get data as xml document using Overpass Api and Draw Map using JAVAFX....
so based on this java Example From OpenStreetMap Documentation:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Java_Access_Example
I can get data (using HTTP query) and I draw it.

The problem is that I dont know what zoom level this data refer to ...
I need to create slider with JavaFx and draw all Zoom levels ...
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

So there is anyway to specify the zoom level ? in OverPass QL Query ? OR http query ? or any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw OSM data has no relation to zoom levels. In case of Overpass API you just specify a bounding box and an optional filter. The result will contain all data in the bounding box (matching the filter) with full details, no matter how small or unimportant an object is.

Zoom levels are only relevant to [slippy maps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map). Here, the zoom level defines which objects to show and which to hide. Usually you don't want to see traffic signals, benches or playgrounds at low zoom levels.